# 100% height div won't scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I'm currently working on a chat site and am encountering a strange issue when working with the chat display. Right now, I have a `div` that my jQuery dynamically adds chat rows to. I want to have the `div` have a height of 100% so that I can get it to size according to the user's configuration, but when I do so, the `div` expands instead of scrolling.

I have done a bunch of research, but with no luck. For example, I have tried forcing `overflow-y: scroll` in my CSS, setting `max-height` to 100%, but still no luck. The interesting thing that I have noted, however, is that the issue doesn't seem to happen in Chrome, but does reproduce in Firefox 31.0 and IE 11.

Here's my HTML (modified to only show the relevant parts):

```
<html height="100%">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/style.css"> <!-- Mainly background colors, etc -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/chat.css"> <!-- Most of this page's styling comes from here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/buttons.css"> <!-- Reskining the bootstrap buttons -->
    <script src="./javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./javascripts/chat.js"></script> <!-- the js that facilitates chatting -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="./dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body style="background-color: #ccc;" height="100%" width="100%">
        <div id="pageHeader" width="100%" height="20%">
            ...
        </div>
        <table width="100%" height="70%" style="margin: 0px">
            <tr width="100%" height="70%">
                <td width="60%" height="100%">
                    <div id="msgWindow" class="shadow"></div> <!-- The is is the div I'm referring to -->
                </td>
                <td width="25%" height="100%">
                    <div id="roomWindow" class="shadow" height="100%"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" height="100%">
                    ...
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="15%">
                ...
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table height="10%" width="100%">
            <tr height="95%" width="100%">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%" width="100%">
                <td><p style="color:grey">BETA 1.0</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

chat.css:

```
#msgWindow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

h1{
    color: #3366BB;
}

#roomWindow {
  background-color: #fff;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #000000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.allMsg {
    max-width: 550px !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;

}

.userSpan {
    font-size: 9pt;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

The JS I use when dynamically adding the chat rows looks like this:

```
var html = "<tr><td class='userSpan'>" + msg.source + "</td><td class='allMsg'>" + msg.message + "</td>";
$('#msgWindow').append(html);
```

style.css doesn't contain any layout stuff, just colors and font.

I've spent way too long looking at this trying to fix it, so I must be overlooking something incredibly simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

height 100% does not work with scrolls. You need to give a height to one of the wrapper. In your question you have mentioned that the height is coming from a user configuration, so then there won't be a problem. You can put the configuration height as inline css for the **td** or **#msgWindow** container as below. You can add height using PHP or Javascript as inline

Assume configuration height for this user = 200px

Add Height to **td**

```
<tr width="100%" height="70%">
    <td width="60%" style="height:200px;" >
       <div id="msgWindow" class="shadow"></div> <!-- The is is the div I'm referring to -->
    </td>
    <td width="25%" height="100%">
       <div id="roomWindow" class="shadow" height="100%"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Add Height to **#msgWindow**

```
<tr width="100%" height="70%">
    <td width="60%">
       <div id="msgWindow" class="shadow" style="height:200px;" ></div> <!-- The is is the div I'm referring to -->
    </td>
    <td width="25%" height="100%">
       <div id="roomWindow" class="shadow" height="100%"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't overly clear what I meant by configuration in the main question. I just meant the user's window size, instead of something they configured manually. This solution will probably work, but it removes the ability of the user to change the window size and have it adapt. Do you know if there's a JS method that checks for screen size (viewport) change that I could use to replicate the functionality?

Comment: Do you need to adapt the height when window is resizing? tell me this, do you want total window height to takse as the height of the #msgWindow and window is resizing #msgWindow height should resize along with the screen size?